# High School polynomial

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms

Been stuck on this one for a while now...

What is the standard term for a second-order polynomial when the first-order factor is 3, the sum of the zeros is 5, and the product of the zeros is 15

Comment: The zeros mean roots

Comment: If $r,s$ are the roots of a polynomial, then the polynomial is of the form $a(x-r)(x-r)=ax^2-a(r+s)x+ars$. If $r+s=5$, $rs=15$ and $-a(r+s)=3$, then you can find that $a=-3/5$ and you get all its coefficients: $(-3/5)x^2+3x+(-3/5)15$.

Comment: Thanks a lot bud!!!!!!!